# dayjs return invalid date from format string

Tags: javascript

I try to parse the date from a string but I got invalid date.

Seems I doing something incorrect here but can't find out why. I give the string and the format to parse from. as I say I get invalid date.

How to do it correctly?

```
import dayjs from 'dayjs';

console.clear();

const i = '28-04-2021';

const b = dayjs(i, 'DD-MM-YYYY').toDate();

console.log({ b }); // output invalid date.
```

[codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-zhukovsky-ddu4c?file=/src/index.ts)

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: well, I know I can use dayjs plugin. but even without the plugin I have a constructor that takes many overload. and in the one of the options I have `ctor(string, format)`. so I ask because seems the dayjs have built in without the plugin. this is very confuse me.

Comment: [Docs -> Parse -> String + Format](https://day.js.org/docs/en/parse/string-format): _"This dependent on CustomParseFormat plugin to work"_ - right at the top, in a highlighted yellow box...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [doc](https://day.js.org/docs/en/plugin/custom-parse-format) you are missing this lines of code

```
import customParseFormat from 'dayjs/plugin/customParseFormat';
dayjs.extend(customParseFormat);
```

then you can use this type of constructor `dayjs(date, format)`.

to use it globally, i would recommend to put it at the top of the project. In your example, put it right after import of `dayjs`.